# jquery tabs change background picture when tab changes

Tags: jquery, tabs

How can I change the panel's background picture, whenever a tab changes?

I need to change the .ui-tabs-panel css dynamically

I hve tried this but it seems to work only when the page is loaded, then the tabs panel goes back to the stylesheet value

```
$( "#mytabs" ).tabs({

     select: function(event, ui) {

        // Do your validation here
         $('.ui-tabs-panel').css('background-image','bo.jpg');



          /* */
    }       

    });
```

});

Thanks

Comment: jo8 I understand too few basics in jquery to be able to write to you what I have tried, I know I have to catch an event and then change the object property but I have no real clue how to achieve that

Comment: You would want to select the target element that needs the background, then change the background css property using the `.css` method.

Comment: thanks, how do i select the target element?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for not helping me, I have found the solution myself...

And I am posting it here for others that may need it:

```
 $( "#mytabs" ).tabs({

     select: function(event, ui) {

        // Do your validation here
         $('.ui-tabs-panel').css('background-image',"url('yourimage.jpg')");



          /* */
    }       

    });
```